# Calling a new View After a method executes in another method

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I am making an iOS application and I have this method that runs in a thread, and i am also calling another method in this method, but at the point of execution of the second method, crashes the application, actually, i want to move to a new view after the second method succesfully executes.

Any help will be appreciated. request for the code may be welcome.

Comment: We definitely need to see code. And the crash would be helpful too... We can't fix the problem if you don't show us the problem or the steps you followed to get to the problem.

Comment: Is the second method is thread safe (doesn't affect the UI)?

Answer (score 1):

The UI is not thread safe. Hence, you should only update the UI from the main thread.

To force code to run on the main thread, you can use a block like this in a thread or other block:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  // Update UI here
});
```